# Reversing values in a column

Tags: r, dplyr, reverse

My data is something like this. I want to reverse the values of column B.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(  "Not at all"  ,"Several days" ,  "More than half the days",  "Nearly every day "),
                 B = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

So, I want to have it like this.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(  "Not at all"  ,"Several days" ,  "More than half the days",  "Nearly every day "),
                 B = c(4, 3, 2, 1))
```

rev is not working with my data and the structure of the data is :

```
'data.frame':   511 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ id...1          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Q3.2_1...2      : num  1 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ id...3          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Q3.2_1...4      : chr  "Several days" "Not at all" "Not at all" "Nearly every day" ...
 $ newcolumn.id    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ newcolumn.Q3.2_1: chr  "Several days" "Not at all" "Not at all" "Nearly every day"
```

I want to reverse Q3.2_1 num.

Comment: df$B <- rev(df$B), but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
df$B <- rev(df$B)
```

Output:

```
df
                        A B
1              Not at all 4
2            Several days 3
3 More than half the days 2
4       Nearly every day  1
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(B=rev(B))
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried both but they are not working

Comment: @AliRoghani In your dummy data works, please check if your original data the var is numeric!

Comment: @AliRoghani `rev` is a standard function.  It should work.  I agree with Duck that in your example, it is working correctly.  May be your original data structure is not similar to what you showed in the example? Please check the `str(yourdf)`. It also works on `factor` `rev(factor(c('a', 'b', 'd')))`

Comment: Yeah @akrun is right, something in the structure of your data is not working properly as you see the rev code in your sample data is working!

Comment: I am adding the str of my data now